# How can I create a new ViewPager in froid

Tags: android, frege

I'm using [froid](https://github.com/mchav/froid) to write Android applications and I can't seem to find documentation on how to make a ViewPager.

How do I go about making a custom one?

Comment: Perhaps it is best to ask the author directly by opening an issue on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Froid assigns function closures to objects instead of overriding them - which means that you never have to make a custom class that overrides `ViewPager` you only need to give froid's `ViewPager` class functions that determine how you want the `ViewPager` to work. These are called `delegators` in the API.

For example, in the [TryFrege](https://github.com/mchav/try-frege-android/blob/master/app/src/main/frege/io/github/mchav/tryfrege/MainActivity.fr#L75) app there is a custom instance of `ViewPager`.